# How to get origin and destination points while searching with mapbox

Tags: java, mapbox

1. public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
   OnMapReadyCallback, PermissionsListener {

   ```
   private static final int REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE = 1;
   // variables for adding location layer
   private MapView mapView;
   private MapboxMap mapboxMap;

   // variables for adding location layer
   private PermissionsManager permissionsManager;
   private LocationComponent locationComponent;

   // variables for calculating and drawing a route
   private DirectionsRoute currentRoute;
   private static final String TAG = "DirectionsActivity";
   private NavigationMapRoute navigationMapRoute;

   // variables needed to initialize navigation
   private Button button;
   private CarmenFeature home;
   private CarmenFeature work;
   private String geojsonSourceLayerId = "geojsonSourceLayerId";
   private String symbolIconId = "symbolIconId";

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       // Mapbox access token is configured here. This needs to be called either in your application
       // object or in the same activity which contains the mapview.
       Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.access_token));

       // This contains the MapView in XML and needs to be called after the access token is configured.
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
       mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       mapView.getMapAsync(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void onMapReady(@NonNull final MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
       this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap;
       mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS, new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
           @Override
           public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {

               enableLocationComponent(style);
               addDestinationIconSymbolLayer(style);

               initSearchFab();

               addUserLocations();

               // Add the symbol layer icon to map for future use
               style.addImage(symbolIconId, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                       MainActivity.this.getResources(), R.drawable.mapbox_marker_icon_default));

               // Create an empty GeoJSON source using the empty feature collection
               setUpSource(style);

               // Set up a new symbol layer for displaying the searched location's feature coordinates
               setupLayer(style);
           }
       });
   }

   //search
   private void initSearchFab() {
       findViewById(R.id.fab_location_search).setOnClickListener(new
   ```

   View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {
                   Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder()
                           .accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken() != null ? Mapbox.getAccessToken() : getString(R.string.access_token))
                           .placeOptions(PlaceOptions.builder()
                                   .backgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EEEEEE"))
                                   .limit(10)
                                   .addInjectedFeature(home)
                                   .addInjectedFeature(work)
                                   .build(PlaceOptions.MODE_CARDS))
                           .build(MainActivity.this);
                   startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE);
               }
           });
       }

   ```
   //home and work
   private void addUserLocations() {
       home = CarmenFeature.builder().text("Mapbox SF Office")
               .geometry(Point.fromLngLat(-122.3964485, 37.7912561))
               .placeName("50 Beale St, San Francisco, CA")
               .id("mapbox-sf")
               .properties(new JsonObject())
               .build();

       work = CarmenFeature.builder().text("Mapbox DC Office")
               .placeName("740 15th Street NW, Washington DC")
               .geometry(Point.fromLngLat(-77.0338348, 38.899750))
               .id("mapbox-dc")
               .properties(new JsonObject())
               .build();
   }

   private void setUpSource(@NonNull Style loadedMapStyle) {
       loadedMapStyle.addSource(new GeoJsonSource(geojsonSourceLayerId));
   }

   private void setupLayer(@NonNull Style loadedMapStyle) {
       loadedMapStyle.addLayer(new SymbolLayer("SYMBOL_LAYER_ID", geojsonSourceLayerId).withProperties(
               iconImage(symbolIconId),
               iconOffset(new Float[] {0f, -8f})
       ));
   }

   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE) {

           // Retrieve selected location's CarmenFeature
           CarmenFeature selectedCarmenFeature = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(data);

           // Create a new FeatureCollection and add a new Feature to it using selectedCarmenFeature above.
           // Then retrieve and update the source designated for showing a selected location's symbol layer icon

           if (mapboxMap != null) {
               Style style = mapboxMap.getStyle();
               if (style != null) {
                   GeoJsonSource source = style.getSourceAs(geojsonSourceLayerId);
                   if (source != null) {
                       source.setGeoJson(FeatureCollection.fromFeatures(
                               new Feature[] {Feature.fromJson(selectedCarmenFeature.toJson())}));
                   }

                   // Move map camera to the selected location
                   mapboxMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(
                           new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                   .target(new LatLng(((Point) selectedCarmenFeature.geometry()).latitude(),
                                           ((Point) selectedCarmenFeature.geometry()).longitude()))
                                   .zoom(14)
                                   .build()), 4000);
               }
           }
       }
   }


   //getRoute
   private void getRoute(Point origin, Point destination)
   {
       NavigationRoute.builder(this)
               .accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken())
               .origin(origin)
               .destination(destination)
               .build()
               .getRoute(new Callback<DirectionsResponse>()
               {
                   //onResponse
                   @Override
                   public void onResponse(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Response<DirectionsResponse> response)
                   {
                       // You can get the generic HTTP info about the response
                       Log.d(TAG, "Response code: " + response.code());
                       if (response.body() == null)
                       {
                           Log.e(TAG, "No routes found, make sure you set the right user and access token.");
                           return;
                       }
                       else if (response.body().routes().size() < 1)
                       {
                           Log.e(TAG, "No routes found");
                           return;
                       }

                       currentRoute = response.body().routes().get(0);

                       // Draw the route on the map
                       if (navigationMapRoute != null)
                       {
                           navigationMapRoute.removeRoute();
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           navigationMapRoute = new NavigationMapRoute(null, mapView, mapboxMap,
   ```

   R.style.NavigationMapRoute);
                           }
                           navigationMapRoute.addRoute(currentRoute);
                       }//end of onResponse

   ```
                   //onFailure
                   @Override
                   public void onFailure(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Throwable throwable)
                   {
                       Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + throwable.getMessage());
                   }//end of onFailure
               });
   }//end of getRoute

   //addDestinationIconSymbolLayer
   private void addDestinationIconSymbolLayer(@NonNull Style loadedMapStyle)
   {
       loadedMapStyle.addImage("destination-icon-id",
               BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.mapbox_marker_icon_default));
       GeoJsonSource geoJsonSource = new GeoJsonSource("destination-source-id");
       loadedMapStyle.addSource(geoJsonSource);
       SymbolLayer destinationSymbolLayer = new SymbolLayer("destination-symbol-layer-id", "destination-source-id");
       destinationSymbolLayer.withProperties(
               iconImage("destination-icon-id"),
               iconAllowOverlap(true),
               iconIgnorePlacement(true)
       );
       loadedMapStyle.addLayer(destinationSymbolLayer);
   }//end of addDestinationIconSymbolLayer

   //enableLocationComponent
   @SuppressWarnings({"MissingPermission"})
   private void enableLocationComponent(@NonNull Style loadedMapStyle)
   {
       // Check if permissions are enabled and if not request
       if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this))
       {
           // Activate the MapboxMap LocationComponent to show user location
           // Adding in LocationComponentOptions is also an optional parameter
           locationComponent = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent();
           locationComponent.activateLocationComponent(this, loadedMapStyle);
           locationComponent.setLocationComponentEnabled(true);
           // Set the component's camera mode
           locationComponent.setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING);
       }
       else
       {
           permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this);
           permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this);
       }
   }//end of enableLocationComponent

   //onRequestPermissionsResult
   @Override
   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
   {
       permissionsManager.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
   }//end of onRequestPermissionsResult

   //onExplanationNeeded
   @Override
   public void onExplanationNeeded(List<String> permissionsToExplain)
   {
       Toast.makeText(this, R.string.user_location_permission_explanation,
   ```

   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }//end of onExplanationNeeded

   ```
   //onPermissionResult
   @Override
   public void onPermissionResult(boolean granted)
   {
       if (granted)
       {
           enableLocationComponent(mapboxMap.getStyle());
       }
       else
       {
           Toast.makeText(this, R.string.user_location_permission_not_granted,
   ```

   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               finish();
           }
       }//end of onPermissionResult

   ```
   // Add the mapView lifecycle to the activity's lifecycle methods
   @Override
   public void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       mapView.onResume();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onStart() {
       super.onStart();
       mapView.onStart();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onStop() {
       super.onStop();
       mapView.onStop();
   }

   @Override
   public void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       mapView.onPause();
   }

   @Override
   public void onLowMemory() {
       super.onLowMemory();
       mapView.onLowMemory();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
       mapView.onDestroy();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
       super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
       mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
   } }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please detail what you would like to achieve?

Origin and destination are just 2 positions on the map. You can retrieve these in multiple ways. You could select them by clicking on the map, entering an address into a geocoder that would translate the address to a geolocation. Therefore you could make use of the [Mapbox Places Plugin.](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/overview/places/)

This example lets you select features of the map by clicking on it. You can adapt it and return the geolocation, which in turn you could use as your destination: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/query-a-map-feature/

You can make use of the Mapbox locationComponent and retrieve the current device location, which you could utilize as your origin.
See this example: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/show-a-users-location/

In below snippet, you could use the location `loc` as origin:

```js
      private void enableLocationComponent(@NonNull Style loadedMapStyle) {

        if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this)) {

           LocationComponent locationComponent = map.getLocationComponent();
           Location loc = locationComponent.getLastKnownLocation();
```

Comment: Hi, so I have managed to search my destination but I don't know how to make it equal to my destination point so I can create a route from the users last know location to the place that has been searched.